# Proof of the Propeller theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

Made this animation of the propellor theorem but don't know the neatest and best way to prove it?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THS4IvNywk8

any Ideas?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the theorem but it looks like there a discussion and proof at https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/AsymmetricPropeller2.shtml

Comment: The animation is great, I would suggest taking some screen-shoots and add a few pictures to attract more attention, but I really like the effort.